# Trouble with PHP get contents + API

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

I am trying to create an Adfly shortener website for my associates to use using PHP. I thought this would be simple, but I am having some trouble getting this to work

```
$longURL = $_GET['longurl'];

$shortURL = shortAdfly($longURL);

// Print the result
print_r($shortURL);

// Adf.ly shortener
function shortAdfly($ToConvert) {
    urlencode($ToConvert);
    $apiUrl = 'http://api.adf.ly/api.php?' . http_build_query([
    'key' => 'My API Key',
    'uid' => 'My User ID',
    'advert_type' => 'int',
    'domain' => 'adf.ly',
    'url' => $ToConvert ]);
    $short_url = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
    return $short_url;
}
```

Comment: use `print_r($shortURL);` not `echo $shortURL`

Comment: @Tiny Giant, I changed the API a little bit :)

Comment: @aldrin, That sadly, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You probably need to URL encode the `$ToConvert`, eg `$APIlink . urlencode($ToConvert)`. Debugging the final URL used in `file_get_contents()` should show you what's going wrong

Comment: @aldrin27 makes a debug. What is the result you get?

Comment: @Phil I added in the encoding. No help.

Comment: Ok, what is the response you're getting back? Also, why are you setting the `$use_include_path` argument for `file_get_contents()` to `true`?

Comment: @Phil I have updated my coding above to this. I am not receiving errors, but I am not receiving a link when I am using it on my actual website. It is also not making a link when I go to my account on Adfly.com.

Comment: What **exactly** are you receiving?

Comment: @Phil, I am receiving nothing in my HTML code or on the Adfly website itself.

Comment: @Phil, Could this be a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

Building URL query strings by hand is like encoding JSON by hand; you just shouldn't do it. Use the tools provided

```
$apiUrl = 'http://api.adf.ly/api.php?' . http_build_query([
    'key'         => 'your-api-key',
    'uid'         => 1234567,
    'advert_type' => 'int',
    'domain'      => 'adf.ly',
    'url'         => $ToConvert
]);
return file_get_contents($apiUrl);
```

Comment: I have updated my coding above to this. I am not receiving errors, but I am not receiving a link when I am using it on my actual website. It is also not making a link when I go to my account on Adfly.com.